# Logging into DSM7 NAS hangs after entering password

Tags: login, synology

My network is based on Ubiquiti Unifi devices and has some printers and assorted clients, and a Synology NAS running DSM7.

A few days ago the network suddenly developed [problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127565/unifi-usg-3-vs-isp-pppoe-i-can-ping-the-isps-network-but-not-outside-of-it). It's beginning to become a critical issue, but I'm stumped.

Of note is that I can access the NAS via SSH, and I can access the login page, but I cannot login. What happens is that I provide the admin name and hit enter, and then provide the password and hit enter, and then ... spinner never stops spinning, page never switches, process never times out.

What gives? How can I troubleshoot this?

I have made zero changes to any of the network devices these past two weeks, but it may be related to my other issue, that the NAS is also serving as a Unifi controller, and the network has been behaving weirdly (without any configuration changes).

---

[image: screen shot of system load]

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I'd probably be opening a support case with Synology. If you want to look around, I'd start by SSH'ing and checking whether there are some processes taking up a lot of CPU. You could try a restart via SSH also.

Comment: @fission, I've restarted the box several times already, that doesn't change anything. The load seems rather normal, I think (see screen shot in question).