# Unifi USG-3 vs ISP (PPPoE): I can ping the ISP's network, but not outside of it

Tags: networking, pppoe

Our network is based on Ubiquiti Unifi devices and has some printers and assorted clients, and a Synology NAS running DSM7.

A few days ago the network suddenly developed problems, although I have made zero changes to any of the network devices these past two weeks. It's beginning to become a critical issue, but I'm stumped.

It's not a large network:

- Fiber connection enters the premises
- Fiber/ethernet media converter (zero configuration options, and owned by ISP)
- Ubiqiti USG ("Unifi Security Gateway")
- Ubiqiti Unifi Switch
- Ubiqiti Unifi access points
- misc. clients, printers, ...
- Synology NAS (the Unifi controller is running in a Docker container, along with other server tasks)

Of note is that the USG has a PPPoE configuration (username, password, VLAN) that must match what is provided by the ISP. This has been working fine "since forever". However, a few days ago the internet connection just ... dropped. From talking with the ISP tech support, their connection up to the USG checks out, and from what I can tell via Unifi our network also checks out. And yet, no connection.

Or is there?

It turns out that I can actually ping the ISP's default gateway (94.144.1.4), and I can also ping other addresses on the ISP's network (variations on our own public IP; variations on their gateway IP) but I cannot ping anything outside of the ISP's network (eg. 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8) -- heck, not even their own preferred DNS servers (eg. 212.242.40.3)!

Because they say that there is a connection into our premises, the problem must be on our end. I have been unable to obtain any explanation as to why I am able to access only their network but nothing outside.

To me this suggests that the ISP must have made some change that has affected our connection.

What gives? How can I troubleshoot this?

It may be related to my [other issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127563/logging-into-dsm7-nas-hangs-after-entering-password), that the NAS (also serving as a Unifi controller) has been giving me grief with logging into it. I do not suspect a malicious attack, for whatever that's worth.

---

Edit 2: Now that I've received their official equipment, I see the exact same behaviour. At least they're now willing to sic their network team on the issue, so there is hope it will be resolved within the week.

Edit 1: I can't check the routing table as the interface of the USG in stand-alone mode is very simplistic:
[image: main screen]
[image: configuration screen]

Comment: Check the routing table of your USG.

Comment: @vidarlo I've reset the USG so it's in stand-alone mode where there are hardly any options to configure, only PPPoE credentials and LAN DHCP range.

Comment: In your first image, you didn't add any DNS server addresses.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I did, but either they don't "stick" or they're simply not shown.

Comment: Well, what does your routing table look like?

Comment: Can you try to temporary set up the Internet connection on ISP-recommended hardware and check if it works? Then, when *that* works, repeat configuring your USG.

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely what I'm going to do. My ISP "naturally" don't have any wifi routers in the country, so one is being shipped to me.

Comment: Now that I've received their official equipment, I see the exact same behaviour.